# MVC Bundling with Angular-Translate

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, angular-translate, asp.net-bundling

I am having an issue with angular-translate (CDN with local fallback) after publishing to our webserver.

I assume the issue is down to the minification process of MVC bundling.

I have the following bundles added to my BundleConfig;

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular-translate",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.10.0/angular-translate.min.js")
        .Include("~/Client/scripts/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular-translate-static-files",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.10.0/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js")
        .Include("~/Client/scripts/angular-translate/services/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular-translate-cookies",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.10.0/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.min.js")
        .Include("~/Client/scripts/angular-translate/services/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular-translate-local-storage",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.10.0/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.min.js")
        .Include("~/Client/scripts/angular-translate/services/angular-translate-storage-local.js"));
```

This is working fine locally but not after being published on the server. where I get the following error;

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n%20%3C-%20%24translateStaticFilesLoader

I assumed that by referencing the .min version file from the CDN this would fix the issue bundling has with the injection issues minification causes angular. However, it doesnt seem to have made any difference?

Does anyone have any idea on how I can still reference the CDN with the local fall back but fix the issue? (or if indeed this is the issue)